# Destructing std::promise immediately when state is ready

Tags: c++, promise, std, future, destructor

Consider the following code:

```
void runSomething() {
   std::promise<void> promise;
   startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread([&]{
     promise.set_value();
   });
   promise.get_future().get();
}
```

This code shows kind of a wrapper over an asynchronous function that calls the lambda when the asynchronous job is complete. After launching the asynchronous job the external function waits to the future to become ready and then exits. The future will become ready by the set_value() call when the asynchronous job will complete.

My question is, is this code valid? Because apparently, the get() function of the future might return immediately when the state of the future become ready, before the set_value() function of the promise returned. This means that the promise destructor might be invoked before the end of the set_value() of the promise object, which seems invalid.

From my experience, I know that the code above should work perfectly, at least on the platform I experienced with. But can you state something that shows that this code has defined behavior?

Comment: If this works as you intend, then you have turned an async function into synchronous function.  My question is why?

Comment: The code snippet is just to demonstrate the question. In my actual code, I had an executor to which I sent multiple jobs, and the last job set the promise and let the external function go. So the function was more that just turning async into sync...

Comment: @Haim Did you consider using `std::async`?

Comment: std::async has a cost of starting a new thread, so if I have a lot of jobs to run, and I want to spread it between threads, using a thread-pool executor might be a better solution for the task.

Comment: @Haim I think you need to measure. Typically, implementations do not _start_ a thread when you use `std::async`. They use the built-in thread-pool, just like algorithms supporting executions policies. It's _possible_ that your implementation actually starts a new thread for each `std::async` but I'd check that out for sure before rejecting it.

Answer (score 3):

You got the usage of the promise the wrong way around. You should first get the future from the promise. After that the promise is of no use for the recieving end but can be moved from:

```cpp
void runSomething() {
    std::promise<void> promise;
    auto fut = promise.get_future();
    startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread([p = std::move(promise)]() mutable {
        p.set_value(); 
    });
    fut.get();
}
```

The `promise` is not meant to be shared. The shared state is managed by the `future`.

`std::promise` is not as *special* as you seem to expect. If two threads concurrently modify the same object you are in trouble.

---

For illustration consider this toy example implementation:

```
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

template <typename F>
void startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread(F f) { f(); }

namespace toy {
    struct shared_state {
        // T value // T is void
        bool ready = false;
        std::mutex mut;
    };

    struct future {
        std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state;
        auto get() { 
            while (true) {
                std::unique_lock l{state->mut};
                if (state->ready) return;                
            }
        }        
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct promise {
        std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state{new shared_state};
        future get_future() { return {state}; }
        void set_value() {
            {
                std::unique_lock l{state->mut};
                state->ready = true;
            }
            // *** something might access promise members here
        }
    };
}


void runSomething() {
   toy::promise<void> promise;
   startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread([&]{
     promise.set_value();         
   });
   promise.get_future().get();
}
```

`promise.set_value` signals that the result is ready to be picked up by `promise.get_future().get()`. The access to the shared state is protected by a mutex, but that does not synchronize all other access to `promise`. Now consider the line marked with `//***`! Once the `mutex` is unlocked, there is no synchronisation between one thread still executing `set_value` while the other thread is already returning from `get` and starts to deconstructor `promise`.

This is of course jsut a toy example. Though `std::promise` also does not give you the guarantees you expect. It is not meant to be accessed concurrently with out synchronization.

Comment: Also, `std::package_task` is a thing.

Comment: Well, if startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread() accepts an std::function, I think this will not work, because the capture variables must be copyable.

In addition, in my actual case I did need to share the promise between multiple jobs that ran on different threads, and the last job to finish set the promise.

Comment: @Haim sorry but I dont understand what you mean. I can only refer to the code you posted in the question. If your actual issue is something else you should open a new question

Comment: @Haim ".. I think this will not work, because the capture variables must be copyable" ? why must the caputures be copyable? `std::promise` is not copyable afaik

Comment: Try to compile this: `std::promise<void> p; std::function<void()> f = [p=std::move(p)]() {};`, you will get an error because std::promise is not copy-constructible, and as a result the lambda object is also not copy-constructible, and std::function can only wrap copy-constructible lambda.

Comment: Also, the question is just whether sharing the promise by reference is also good, because since the get() call keeps the external function scope alive until the value is set, the promise is not destructed before the call to set_value(), so it might be okay to share it.

Comment: "is just whether sharing the promise by reference is also good" no it is not. When one thread calls a method while the other calls the destructor then all bets are off.

Comment: Well, this is actually an answer to the question. But can you find a reference for that? If the destructor is called during a method call by other thread, but the method does not touch the destructing object from the moment the destructor was invoked, then apparently everything is okay.

Comment: @Haim no. I cannot give you a reference. Its a data race, undefined behavior. I tried to add more to the answer, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

For your example to work, you need to move the `promise` into the lambda. If the lambda is to be stored in a `std::function`, then you can't capture it (since `promises` are not copyable) but you can supply it as an argument to the lambda:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::thread th;  // a thread in a thread-pool

void startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread(
    std::function<void(std::promise<void>)> f, std::promise<void> p) 
{
    // simulating handing the promise over to the thread in the pool
    th = std::thread(f, std::move(p));
}

void runSomething() {
    std::future<void> fut;

    { // promise scope
        std::promise<void> promise;
        fut = promise.get_future();

        startWorkAndCallBackFromDifferentThread(
            [](std::promise<void> p) {
                std::cout << "work work...\n";
                p.set_value();
            },
            std::move(promise));
    } // original promise gone, now lives in thread

    fut.get();
    th.join();
}

int main() {
    runSomething(); 
}
```

This is much simpler using `std::async`:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

void runSomething() {
    std::function<int()> backgroundWork = [] {
        // work work
        return 1;
    };

    std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, backgroundWork);

    // store futures somewhere and collect later:

    std::cout << fut.get() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    runSomething();
}
```